# How would I split left and right audio in Windows and handle as independent channels?

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio

I want to handle the left and right stereo channels as if they are totally separate and independent paths.  For example, most Bluetooth speakers have speakers for both channels in one cabinet, and the output is through one Bluetooth connection.

I want to be able to have two independent, single-channel speakers, each with a separate Bluetooth connection, each handling one of the stereo channels, and direct the left channel to one and the right channel to the other.

Is there a way to do this in Windows?

Comment: The ARE split, and will go to different speakers when they are plugged in.  It isn't clear what you're asking.  If you have a stereo jack with a single hole, there are multiple connections inside.  You can buy simple adapters that will give you separate jacks for each channel, if that's what you want.

Comment: @fixer1234 I'm meaning like a port in front and in the back giving separate left and right audio from within windows without using the Stereo Mix, or like two separate Bluetooth speakers for separate left and right audio

Comment: Hey, happy New Year and welcome back.  I'm still missing what you want that's different from what's there.  The left and right channels are separate, although connections for both may be contained in a single jack (the segmented plug makes the connections to all of the individual channel contacts).  If you need to tap the channels separately, you can use a splitter like https://www.amazon.com/eFuture-STR_M-SPL_F-Stereo-Y-Splitter-Female/dp/B0012IYLMM, which just directs each channel's contacts to a separate jack.

Comment: @fixer1234 Happy New Year to you too. Say two bluetooth speakers working separately from each other, one for left audio and one for right, How would I do it from within windows without any extra hardware beside 2 BT dongles each linked to a separate speaker

Comment: OK, so most Bluetooth speakers have speakers for both channels in one cabinet.  You want to be able to have two independent single-channel speakers, each with a separate Bluetooth connection, each handling one channel, and direct the left channel to one and the right channel to the other?  I don't have an answer, but let me take a shot at clarifying the question and see if someone else does.

Comment: @fixer1234 that's a theoretical  situation but, yes, assuming I have both speakers connected in a way that both can be used without overloading the Bluetooth card/dongle or one of each connection

Comment: Does the edit get closer to what you're after?  Feel free to tweak it as needed if not.  This will at least bump it on the main page and give people a better idea of where you're trying to go.  Hopefully an answer to this case would be adaptable to other situations.

Comment: @fixer1234 yes, thank you, your username fits you well

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways this can be accomplished if you have two Bluetooth speaker devices.

1. Both connected directly to the PC + special software.
2. Both connected to separate [Bluetooth transmitters](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=bluetooth+transmitter) + a [special Y-splitter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000068O5H) cable that splits the left and right channels to separate wires.

**For Both Directly Connected to PC**

By default, all software on Windows plays audio to *just one* audio device.
You are going to need a software workaround to allow most programs to be able to play to two devices at the same time. You can use [Virtual Audio Cable](https://vac.muzychenko.net/en/) to "route" the playback from your main device to multiple other devices on your PC. Other software exists to do this if you wish to look further.

When you connect a Bluetooth speaker to Windows it will show up as a playback device in the Windows Sound Control Panel. When both speakers are connected to the PC you should be able to see both in this list. (Warning: Some Bluetooth adapters don't support multiple audio devices concurrently!)

In the Sound Control Panel, you should be able to open the Properties for each Bluetooth device and adjust their Left/Right volumes independently:
[image: Balance Adjustment]

Turn down the left volume on the right speaker, and the right volume on the left speaker.

Finally, use Virtual Audio Cable or your preferred software to play the audio to both Bluetooth devices at the same time.

One last caveat is that some Bluetooth devices are actually stereo with multiple speakers inside, so setting the balance like this may turn off one of the speakers and it may seem quieter.

I have never tried this myself, so if the Balance setting doesn't exist for your particular Bluetooth device you may need to try another device or even another Bluetooth adapter.